# Why doesn't seek work when reading from /dev/stdin?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to use `seek` to "rewind" to the beginning of a file using the following code:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $infile = $ARGV[0];
open (FH, "<$infile");

while(<FH>) {
    chomp;
    print $_,"\n";
}

print "one time","\n";

seek FH, 0, 0;

while(<FH>) {
    chomp;
    print $_,"\n";
}
```

My input file looks like this:

```
A   A   A   A   A   A   A 
B   B   B   B   B   B   B
```

I run my program with the following command:

```
cat file | perl script.pl /dev/stdin
```

But instead of getting my expected output:

```
A   A   A   A   A   A   A 
B   B   B   B   B   B   B
one time
A   A   A   A   A   A   A 
B   B   B   B   B   B   B
```

I get:

```
A   A   A   A   A   A   A 
B   B   B   B   B   B   B
one time
```

Why?

Comment: @toolic I did, but the same as previous ;(

Comment: according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043592/perl-re-reading-from-already-read-filehandle

Comment: I comment both local::lib and use Fcntl; out but it is strange that I can not get the expected output!!!

Comment: Try checking `seek`'s return value. It should return 1 on success, false otherwise.

Comment: I removed all but I do not know why still does not work! updated above script!

Comment: I got it; I use " cat file | perl script.pl /dev/stdin" then I get half of the expected output, but I put the file "perl script.pl file" now work, do you know why?

Comment: Pipes are not seekable?

Comment: `perl -we 'open my $fh, "<", "/dev/stdin" or die $!; seek $fh, 0, 0 or die $!;` gives `Illegal seek at -e line 1.`

Comment: Perl can read from a file passed as an argument, so you should never need to do `cat file | perl script.pl /dev/stdin` instead of `perl script.pl file`

Comment: It does work if `/dev/stdin` refers to a file rather than a pipe: `perl script.pl /dev/stdin < /etc/motd`. To see errors, change your `seek` line to `seek FH, 0, 0 or die "seek: $!\n";`

Comment: Why are you invoking the script using `perl script.pl`. The whole point of the `#!` line is that you don't have to invoke `perl` explicitly; you can just execute the script: `./script.pl`

Answer (score 3):

Pipes are not seek-able,

```
seq 5 | perl -Mautodie -pe 'seek ARGV,0,0 if eof'
```

gives `Can't seek('ARGV', '0', '0'): Illegal seek at -e line 1`, but in case of file it works as expected.